# What is a Duplex and Max #6 Biscuit?

Tags: joinery

What is a Duplex and Max #6 Biscuit?

A [Porter-Cable joiner](https://amzn.to/35kkHhj) info indicates "seven-position rotating depth stop works for standard #0, #10, #20 as well as Simplex, Duplex, and Max (#6) joinery".

[It seems](https://sawmillcreek.org/showthread.php?10128-Biscuits-Joiner-question) simplex is made by a high end manufacturer Lamello.

Are these products no longer offered? Is that why an answer isn't more readily available?

Comment: It might help if you indicate which model Porter-Cable biscuit joiner you're talking about. Even better if you include a link to the documentation.

Comment: Is there a woodworking problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: I had always understood 'max' to be the maximum stroke.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reading that as a list of three distinct items, of which the third is "Max (#6)". i.e., not two items that are Simplex; mostly because "Simplex Duplex" makes no sense.

They probably mean an "S6" biscuit, which is dimensioned 85 x 30 x 4mm. The internet tells me this is a proprietary size, but it looks like Porter-Cable supports it.

That is one large biscuit.

Comment: it seems the S6 biscuit has been discontinued and is no longer available. https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx1PKMPYA9YZMHU

Comment: That is the danger of proprietary non-standards!